Visual Studio 2022 でビルド前のイベントでcl.exeへ渡されるコマンドラインを取得したい
ClangSharp というライブラリを使用して、c++プロジェクトのコード解析を行っています。
このライブラリを実行するには、通常のc++プロジェクトをビルドするときと同じようにc++バージョンや定義済みマクロの情報が必要です。
ビルド前イベントのコード解析処理を走らせているため、このタイミングでcl.exeへ渡されるコマンドラインの情報を取得したいと考えています。
現状試していることは、ビルド前イベントで自前でmsbuildを実行して、そこでcl.exeへ渡されるコマンドラインを抽出しています。
解析自体はうまくいっていますが、ビルドを2度行っているというパフォーマンスの問題があります。
その他、cl.exeへ渡される情報を拾う方法以外により良い方法があれば教えていただきたいです。

こんな記事が何かの参考になるかも？ C++ をclang で解析するときに情報をvcxproj から取得する方法

ありがとうございます！
まさに自分がやりたい内容と合致しているので、そちら参考にしてみます。

本題は質問本文の下記部分です。

ClangSharp というライブラリを使用して、c++プロジェクトのコード解析を行っています。
このライブラリを実行するには、通常のc++プロジェクトをビルドするときと同じようにc++バージョンや定義済みマクロの情報が必要です。
ビルド前イベントのコード解析処理を走らせているため、このタイミングでcl.exeへ渡されるコマンドラインの情報を取得したいと考えています。

c++バージョンや定義済みマクロの情報などを取得する手段のひとつとして、ビルド前にcl.exeへ渡される引数を解析を試みていました。
調べているうちに、MSBuildのカスタムタスクとCLタスクを見つけました。
コンパイラツールcl.exeをラップしたタスクのようで、こちらを使用してc++バージョンや最適化オプション、定義済みマクロなどの情報を取得することで解決しました。

自己解決は推奨されていますが、この内容は質問文に対する回答としては不適切です。質問文は「cl.exeへ渡されるコマンドラインを取得したい」であって「取得した内容を使っての処理方法」ではありません。

申し訳ありません、自己解決の回答文が雑過ぎたためで修正いたしました。
質問と本当の疑問ややりたかったことがズレているという訳ではありません。

MSBuildが実際にcl.exeを起動するのはCLタスクです。ここで指定されたパラメーターからコマンドラインオプションを生成しています。ですので、MSBuildの世界で知れる情報は、CLタスクに渡されるパラメーターが限界となります。
CLタスクが起動されるのは、環境によって細かいパスは変わりますが、C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Msbuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targetsで

こんな感じで、ほとんどのパラメーターはClCompileターゲットが実行された時点でのClCompile項目にパラメーターと同名の属性として格納されています。
その上で、ClCompileターゲットが呼び出されるのはC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Msbuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppBuild.targetsの

こんな感じで、BeforeClCompileTargets、BeforeClCompileやAfterClCompileTargets、AfterClCompile辺りになら概ねコンパイルに必要な情報がそろっているのではないでしょうか。


ビルド前イベントで自前でmsbuildを実行して、そこでcl.exeへ渡されるコマンドラインを抽出しています。

コンパイルが通らない状態でコード分析しても仕方がないので、ビルド後の方が適切に思います。Visual C++自身にもコード分析機能はありますが、ビルド後に走るようになっています。また、この機能はcl.exeに内蔵されているため、MSBuild的にはCLタスク内で完結してしまいます。


その他、cl.exeへ渡される情報を拾う方法以外により良い方法があれば教えていただきたいです。

上述の通り、MSBuildではcl.exeに渡される引数は直接は確認できません。ここでCLタスクはTrackedVCToolTask基底タスクの派生クラスとなっていて、実際にはcl.exeが起動されるのではなく、tracker.exeが起動され、tracker.exeがcl.exeを起動しています。この際、tracker.exeはcl.exeのパスやコマンドライン引数を受け取っています。ですので、ここでtracker.exeではなく自前ツールに書き換えてやれば、cl.exeが受け取るコマンドライン引数を知ることができます。（影響が出ないよう、自前ツールが改めてtracker.exeを起動するといいでしょう。）

ご回答ありがとうございます。
コード解析後、結果に応じて該当プロジェクトのコンパイル対象のソースファイルとして出力する都合で、ビルド前にしておりました。
msbuildの-pp(-preprocessコマンドで、添付画像のようなCLタスクへ渡される情報を確認できました。
ただこの内容を理解して解析するのには苦労しそうです・・・
tracker.exeの存在は知らなかったので調べてみようと思います。
